# Concatenated text file output from single ECHO command gets characters inserted into string printed a second time after expected output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file to insert a string from a *.txt* file at a specific place inside a string in 225 batch files - i.e., inserted into one line in the file at a specific place - but this question concerns the inserting part, and not the loop part, so I've left out the latter in my code example. It's also currently just displaying the text on-screen; not actually writing it to files.

The target files are a bunch of launch *.bat* files used for running a game server cluster using a tool, so I will have to leave each of them with the same names as they start with (*Start XXYY.bat*). They contain something along these lines:

```
start /high ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\ShooterGameServer.exe Ocean?ServerX=0?ServerY=0?AltSaveDirectoryName=0000?ServerAdminPassword=1234?MaxPlayers=50?ReservedPlayerSlots=25?QueryPort=50002?Port=5002?SeamlessIP=192.168.1.225?RCONEnabled=true?RCONPort=28450 -log -server -NoBattlEye
exit
```

Where the *ServerX*, *ServerY*, *AltSaveDirectoryNamen* and all three *Port* settings are unique to each server, so these will have to remain unchanged.

I need to add several more settings, from another *.txt* file in the final version, but for this example I will just put the additions (the word **INSERT** added after the *ReservedPlayerSlots* setting, while keeping each setting divided by question marks) directly into this script.

My code is actually doing exactly what I want it to, but unfortunately it doesn't stop at that point, and decides to append more text than I wanted; specifically, everything I add to the *ECHO* command which is not a variable name.

To clarify, I get the exact output that I want... Plus the unwanted addition of a bunch of question marks and the word **INSERT**, which apparently come from my *ECHO* command, but I just have no idea why they get re-added.

My knowledge of batch scripting is fairly limited, so there might well be something basic that I've overlooked.

I've tried replacing the question marks in the output (which are required to be questions marks in the final version) with normal letters instead, but it doesn't change the behaviour; they were still appended to the expected output, just like the question marks they replaced.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET FileNum=0000
REM I will have the code loop through 225 files (0000-1414) in the final version, but for test purposes I just set it to one single file number manually here.

SET FileName=Start %FileNum%.bat
REN "%FileName%" temp.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 delims=?" %%a IN (temp.txt) DO (
   ECHO %%a?%%b?%%c?%%d?%%e?%%f?%%g?INSERT?%%h?%%i?%%j?%%k?%%l
)
REN temp.txt "%FileName%"
```

I expect this code to output this:

```
start /high ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\ShooterGameServer.exe Ocean?ServerX=0?ServerY=0?AltSaveDirectoryName=0000?ServerAdminPassword=1234?MaxPlayers=50?ReservedPlayerSlots=25?INSERT?QueryPort=50002?Port=5002?SeamlessIP=192.168.1.225?RCONEnabled=true?RCONPort=28450 -log -server -NoBattlEye
exit
```

But what I am getting is this:

```
start /high ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\ShooterGameServer.exe Ocean?ServerX=0?ServerY=0?AltSaveDirectoryName=0000?ServerAdminPassword=1234?MaxPlayers=50?ReservedPlayerSlots=25?INSERT?QueryPort=50002?Port=5002?SeamlessIP=192.168.1.225?RCONEnabled=true?RCONPort=28450 -log -server -NoBattlEye
exit???????INSERT?????
```

Which is the expected output, but with the unexpected re-addition of every symbol in the *ECHO* command which did not designate a variable at the end of the output (in this case **???????INSERT?????**), just after the **exit**.

I'm stumped... I hope someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The second line in your files (`exit`) don't have that many tokens. Are they like your example (exactly two lines, the second one just `exit`?) If yes, you don't really need `exit`.

Comment: What about preceding your `echo` line with this: `if not "%%b"==""`?

Comment: you can replace `"tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` with `tokens=1-12` Also, preferbly enclose your set command in double quotes. `set "FileName=Start %FileNum%.bat"`

Comment: For the first question: Yes, all the batch files I need to edit have this structure; two lines, with the second one just containing the word `exit`.

Preceding the `ECHO` line with `IF NOT "%%b"==""` seems to eliminate the issue, but it also removes that last `exit` line from the file at the same time... It might be possible to use this; I think it should be managable to add the missing line to the file afterwards. I'm not really sure why this works, though...?

I tried replacing `1,2,(...),11,12` with `1-12` and added the quotes to the set command, but i still get the exact same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I applied the idea that aschipfl provided, and it seems to work now.

The `IF NOT "%%b"==""` line seems to have done the trick, after I added the final line with the **exit** using another *ECHO*. My full script (including loop and write to file) is now like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "Insert=SettingOne=True?SettingTwo=False?SettingThree=1.000000"
FOR /l %%x IN (0, 1, 14) DO (
    FOR /l %%y IN (0, 1, 14) DO (
        IF %%x LSS 10 (SET XNum=0%%x) ELSE (SET XNum=%%x)
        IF %%y LSS 10 (SET YNum=0%%y) ELSE (SET Ynum=%%y)
        SET "FileNum=!XNum!!YNum!"
        SET "FileName=Start !FileNum!.bat"
        ECHO Filename: !FileName!
        REN "!FileName!" temp.txt
        (
            FOR /F "tokens=1-12 delims=?" %%a IN (temp.txt) DO (
                IF NOT "%%b"=="" (
                    ECHO %%a?%%b?%%c?%%d?%%e?%%f?%%g?%Insert%?%%h?%%i?%%j?%%k?%%l
                    ECHO exit
                )
            )
        ) >edited.txt
        REN edited.txt "!FileName!"
        DEL /q temp.txt
        ECHO has been updated
    )
)
```

This is now working exactly as intended.

It's quite possible that there is a more elegant way of doing this, and I am cartain that there is a way of making this more general and less hard-coded, but it's good enough for my purposes.

I thank you for your help!